# How to build an offline supporting web application with AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

We have been starting out on building a simple web application on AngularDart 2.

What is the best way to have it runnable on the clients even though they lost internet connection? Right now I am using Lawndart library to use the local storage for saving some data received from REST-Api and it's working fine. But I haven't figured out how to tell the client browsers to cache all sources and use them when having no internet connection. (Right now I am simply using my Redstone-Dart Server (on which the REST-Services are running) for providing the sources)

I've stumbled upon the Angular Mobile Toolkit (https://mobile.angular.io/guides/), but it is only for TypeScript, or is there a way to use it with Dart?

Also later in the project it might be necessary to send push notifications to the clients...is this possible with Dart and Angular 2?

Comment: Don't really know why no one has recommended you look at PouchDB It is designed specifically for this. Hope it helps. Dart implementation: https://github.com/shamblett/sporran DartLang Documentation on it: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sporran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the following point:

> cache all sources and use them when having no internet connection

Although deprecated and having a bad reputation, I still personally use AppCache (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). I understand the solution looks so 2005 when people talk about progressive apps and service worker. It is the only cross-browser solution that works now.

It is easy to setup (just serve a manifest.appcache). For angular application, it mostly contains index.html, main.dart.js and external dependencies.
For me it works on Safari, Chrome and Firefox (cannot tell for IE/Edge). As iOS was a need for me, I could not find another alternative (service worker). Chrome is starting to send a warning for non https sites but so far so good.

Real push notifications are more complex in a web environment; I personally use Firebase realtime database to "push" updates

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got it to work with the app cache approach, wanted to add an answer myself today...I had just a typo in my appcache file, and when one file can not be loaded, the whole appcache won't work. Regarding the firebase approach, do you use it in addition to a self implemented backend server, or do you only have the firebase server which provides the data and the files? And is it possible to host a firebase server yourself?

Comment: Yes the appcache has some limitation. I just use firebase for authentication and push like mechanism (the appengine docs actually recommend to switch from channel - the old real time solution - to firebase: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel). I don't store data in firebase as I have an appengine java backend for now. I just use firebase to notify clients that they have data to pull from the backend...And as far as I know, no, you cannot host a firebase server.

Comment: If you want a pure dart with no external dependencies, I can recommend another solution I had with a dart only server (shelf + rpc + mongo): Use websocket for real time notification. I don't know about redstone (which is based on shelf right?) but shelf has a nice way to integrate websocket

Comment: OK, I will have a look! Thanks!